# Fill top of concrete block wall?

Tags: basement-insulation

I'm planning on adding rigid foam to insulate my basement walls.  The walls are hollow cinder block walls.  Should I fill the tops with spray foam?

Comment: Do you mean that they're open hollow blocks inside? Like from within your basement you can look down into the blocks?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.